# Angular: Testing Http POST method

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test, angular-unit-test

I have a simple service method that does an `http post` call to add a todoList:

```
add(event: any): Observable<TodoList> {
    let todoListToAdd: TodoList = { name: event.target.value, listItems: []};
    return this.http.post<TodoList>("https://localhost:44305/todolist", todoListToAdd);
}
```

I want to unit test this method and tried like this:

```
import { TestBed, getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

import { TodolistService } from './todolist.service';
import { TodoList } from './todolist';
import { HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

describe('TodolistService', () => {
  let injector: TestBed;
  let service: TodolistService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
      providers: [ TodolistService ]
    });

    injector = getTestBed();
    service = injector.get(TodolistService);
    httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpMock.verify();
  });

  describe('#getTodoLists', () => {
     it('getTodoLists - when called after add was called once, then it should return 3 todo lists', () => {
      const event = { target: { value: "test" } };
      const expectedTodoList: TodoList = { name: event.target.value, listItems: []};

      service.add(event);
  
      const req = httpMock.expectOne("https://localhost:44305/todolist");
      expect(req.request.method).toBe("POST");
      expect(req.request.body).toEqual(expectedTodoList);
      req.flush(expectedTodoList);
    });
  });
});
```

Why am I getting the following error?

> Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: https://localhost:44305/todolist", found none.

It is exactly the url that I am calling in the add method, why doesn't it find it?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please share your entire `TestBed` configuration and mocks/spies you may have defined.

Comment: hey @PhilippMeissner I've added the whole testclass :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While all your mocks and imports are perfectly fine, you forgot to `subscribe` to the returned observable.
This is important for the underlaying method to actually *run*.
To make it work just `subscribe` to the stream and inside run your assertions.

```
import { TestBed, getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

import { TodolistService } from './todolist.service';
import { TodoList } from './todolist';
import { HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

describe('TodolistService', () => {
  let injector: TestBed;
  let service: TodolistService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
      providers: [ TodolistService ]
    });

    injector = getTestBed();
    service = injector.get(TodolistService);
    httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpMock.verify();
  });

  describe('#getTodoLists', () => {
    it('getTodoLists - when called after add was called once, then it should return 3 todo lists', () => {
      const event = { target: { value: "test" } };
      const expectedTodoList: TodoList = { name: event.target.value, listItems: []};

      service.add(event).subscribe((todoList) => {
        expect(todoList).toEqual(expectedTodoList);
      });

      const req = httpMock.expectOne("https://localhost:44305/todolist");
      expect(req.request.method).toBe("POST");
      expect(req.request.body).toEqual(expectedTodoList);
      req.flush(expectedTodoList); // This will actually "run" the mocked request if there are any subscribers
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks, that helped a bit but the test still fails unfortunately. Now (with the subscribe and the done) I get these errors:

Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
    at <Jasmine>
Error: Expected no open requests, found 1: POST https://localhost:44305/todolist

Shouldnt the httpMock.verify() make sure, that there are no open requests?

Comment: Ah, my bad. Updated my answer. It's been some time since I worked on this part of the tests.